# Advice needed with grabbing numbers from a file and putting them into an array

Tags: c

I am writing a program that grabs numbers from a txt file and puts them into 2 different arrays.

The text file looks like this:

```
    50 40
    250 140
    5 6
    500 50
    300 200
```

I need to get all the numbers in the first column into one array and the second column into the other array.

This is my code so far:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
        FILE * ifp = fopen("input2.txt","r"); //Open the input file
        int cars = 5, i , j; // Initialized cars and counters i and j
        char VIEW[20], BID[20], CLOSE[20];
        int CAR[10], START_BID[10], MIN_INCREASE[10];
        int *b; // Temp pointer to current bid
        int  *m; // Temp pointer to current array of the minimum increase

        strcpy(VIEW, "VIEW");
        strcpy(BID, "BID");
        strcpy(CLOSE, "CLOSE");

     for (i = 0; i < cars; i++) {
         b = &START_BID[i]; // Get pointer to current START_BID
         m = &MIN_INCREASE[i]; // Get pointer to array of current MIN_INCREASE
         fscanf(ifp, "%d", &b[i]);
         for (j = 0; j < cars; j++) {
             fscanf(ifp, "%d", &m[i]);
         }
     }

        printf("%d\n", START_BID);
        printf("%d\n", MIN_INCREASE);

            fclose(ifp);

        return 0;
    }
```

I have it print the contents of the 2 arrays to see if they were pulled correctly.

This is my output:

```
    2686588
    2686548
```

Any ideas on how I can pull the numbers into the correct array?

Comment: @Drieke.. From your code, you are reading `cars * cars` i.e. 25 values for `m[i]`, whereas the file has only 10 values. Can you confirm the logic? Moreover,`fscanf(ifp, "%d", &b[i]);` is reading into `b[i]` which becomes equivalent of `START_BID[i][i]`. Did you face any access violations when you ran this program?

Comment: @Ganesh I did not face any access violations.

Comment: @Drieke.. I get why you didn't get the access violation. In your `for (j = 0; j < cars; j++)` loop, you are overwriting the same variable `cars` times due to this statement`fscanf(ifp, "%d", &m[i]);` where  the address of variable is always `&m[i]` and since your array size is 10 and `i` loop runs for only 5 times, you don't have any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * ifp = fopen("file.txt","r"); //Open the input file
    int cars = 5, i , j; // Initialized cars and counters i and j
    char *view="VIEW", *bid="BID", *CLOSE="CLOSE";
    int CAR[10], START_BID[10], MIN_INCREASE[10];

    for (i = 0; i < cars; i++) 
    {
        fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &START_BID[i],&MIN_INCREASE[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < cars; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", START_BID[i], MIN_INCREASE[i]);
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, to read the data, the first loop has to be modified as thus

```
 for (i = 0; i < cars; i++) {
     fscanf(ifp, "%d", &START_BID[i]);
     fscanf(ifp, "%d", &MIN_INCREASE[i]);
 }
```

and to print the data as separate arrays

```
printf("\nStarting Bids:\t");
for (i = 0; i < cars; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", START_BID[i]);
}

printf("\nMinimum Increase:\t");
for (i = 0; i < cars; i++) {
  printf("%d\t", MIN_INCREASE[i]);
}

printf("\n");
```

With this the output console would look like

```
Starting Bids:  50      250     5       500     300
Minimum Increase:       40      140     6       50      200
```